# interceptors are doubling the requests

Tags: angular

I have two interceptors HttpErrorInterceptor and AuthInterceptor. They have the following order:

```
export const httpInterceptorProviders = [
  { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpErrorInterceptor, multi: true },
  { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true }
];
```

**Problem:** When I subscribe to `this.userService.register()`, it always returns "E-mail in use", even tho the registration was successful and I can see the new user in my database. This leads me to think that the request is being executed twice. It will probably be the same for other HTTP requests.

**Current result:** E-mail already in use. (double request?)

**Expected result:**
Successfully registered.

**Result when I removed HttpErrorInterceptor from providers:**

That was the expected one but "ERROR"?

```
ERROR 
{…}
error: Object { error: SyntaxError, text: "Successfully registered." }
headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: lazyInit() }
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:5000/api/users"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost:5000/api/users"
<prototype>: Object { … }
core.js:6014:19
```

**Result when I removed AuthInterceptor from providers:**

The issue remained here.

```
ERROR 
{…}
error: "E-mail already in use."
headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: lazyInit() }
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:5000/api/users: 400 Bad Request"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 400
statusText: "Bad Request"
url: "http://localhost:5000/api/users"
<prototype>: Object { … }
core.js:6014:19
```

First of all, it's not coming from the back-end because I tested it with NSwag and Postman. It works fine there. Both providers are added in `app.module.ts` and not in a lazy-loaded module as there were similar problems on stackoverflow.

My self-explanation is that both of interceptors are processing same request at once, somehow, even tho `this.userService.register()` is getting called only once (confirmed by console.log).

I don't know how to solve that but it is coming from HttpErrorInterceptor. I was thinking about using `HttpBackend` but I really need those modals from HttpErrorInterceptor to validate errors.

Any ideas?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dziwbx

http-error.interceptor.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { retry, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { HttpErrorHandlerService } from './http-error-handler.service';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private errorHandler: HttpErrorHandlerService) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log(request);

    return next.handle(request)
      .pipe(
        // retry once before checking the error status
        retry(1),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          this.errorHandler.handle(error);
          return throwError(error);
        })
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interceptor has `retry(1)` which is why they are making duplicate requests.

Comment: That was indeed the problem. Thank you!